# Does adding a random intercept for subject address confounding variables within subjects (e.g. sex or age)?

Tags: mixed-model, model-selection, predictor, random-intercepts

Let's say I am interested in identifying associations between a blood protein and disease activity, but I have multiple measurements per subject. Based on a literature review, I expect sex differences in protein levels. Is it necessary to include the effect of sex in my mixed models if I have already included the subject as a random effect?

i.e., given these two models, if I am only interested in the effet of disease activity on protein levels, does it still make sense to include sex as a covariate?

> protein ~  disease_activity + sex + (1|Subject_ID)

> protein ~  disease_activity + (1|Subject_ID)

I find a significant influence of sex on my protein levels, as expected based on the literature. But I have discussed with some colleagues who have told me that since I already add subject as a random effect, any variation included as a result of sex changes are "taken care of" and it is not necessary to include sex as a fixed effect.

Essentially the arguement they are making is that with mixed models, there is no concern with something like an imbalanced sex ratio since the subject ID is included already. I would greatly appreciate being guided to some literature on the matter as I cannot find anything that specifically addresses this.

An example of the kind of data I am modelling, but this issue would arise with any number of subject-specific variables (like age or weight).

| Subject_ID | Time_point | Protein | Disease_activity | Sex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 35.1 | 3 | F |
| 1 | B | 34.6 | 2 | F |
| 2 | A | 35.5 | 3 | M |
| 2 | B | 35 | 3 | M |
| 2 | C | 35 | 1 | M |

Comment: What is the estimate for the effect of disease activity using each model?  What is the standard error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no: including a RANDOM subject level intercept (which is a particular type of "random effect") does NOT account for individual level covariates. What including a random intercept does is allow the model intercept to vary by subject. But it varies RANDOMLY - i.e. according to a normal distribution centered around the overall intercept. The assumption here is that different people have different intercepts, but just due to random variation, not because some KINDS of people have higher intercepts than others. If it is true that sex or something else is related to the DV, then this model will NOT control for that.

The alternative approach is including individual level FIXED effects. This is another way of saying that you include one dummy variable in the model for each person. This approach WILL control for ALL person level factors (sex, race, etc).
However, there are two downsides to this approach. First - you won't be able to control for (or analyze the effect of) any person level variables (like sex) because they will be perfectly colinear with the dummies. The other downside is that this approach is statistically inefficient and will have large standard errors. Running a random intercept model that controls for all relevant confounders will give you smaller errors....but unless you actually DO include all relevant confounders the result will be biased.

You can run a hausmann test to test to see if the two models give significantly different estimates. If the test is significant (meaning the estimates are different) then that suggests that the random intercept model is biased due to uncontrolled person level factors.